# Display messesge wait....as background processing happening

Tags: jsp

I want to display messsge as "Please Wait........" tilll my java code finishes some processing.

page1.jsp - my form where I have text boxes and submit button. 
When click on submit button I am doing form submit and calling page2.jsp

In page2.jsp I am requesting parametrs from page1.jsp and passing to my java method which returns me userid.

```
userid = myclass.mymethod(); 
if(userid!=null){ 
out.println("Record is in process.Please wait"); 
} 
response.sendredirect("page3.jsp?"+userid=userId);
```

in page3.jsp i m doing processing on userid which I got in page2.jsp simultaneously.

```
someid =request.getparameter(userid); 
process(someid );
```

But that "Wait " messge is displayed after all processing is finished. I want to display it as soon as I got userId. And continue in background processing on that userId.

Comment: you have to use ajax to show waiting message...

Comment: Alternatively, you could use out.flush(); but it is not as reliable as what Ramesh suggested.  With the flush method you have to force the browser(mainly IE ) to start rendering by adding padding text at start of page before wait message. Ask for code, if you want it posted.

Comment: @rickz .yes can you please post code ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript to do many things. Here is one idea.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="wait">
Some text here is necessary here for the IE browser to start displaying. 
Otherwise it will wait until it receives enough of a response to begin displaying         anything.
I am not sure how much padding is necessary. This works in IE 8.
<%
  out.print("<little.gif' />");
  out.flush();
  for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
                         out.print("<br/>Processing!");
                         out.flush();
                         Thread.sleep(3000);  //mock processing
  }
%>
<br/></div>
<script>
  alert("Finished processing.");
  document.getElementById("wait").innerHTML = "Here are the results...";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested in IE8 and Chrome 18. If your server has restrictions, then you might have problems. For instance, it won't work on Google App Engine.

```
<html>
<body>
Some text here is necessary here for the IE browser to start displaying. 
Otherwise it will wait until it receives enough of a response to begin displaying      anything.
I am not sure how much padding is necessary. This works in IE 8.
<%
  out.print("<loading.gif' />");
  out.flush();
  //mock processing
  for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
                         out.print("<br/>Processing!");
                         out.flush();
                         Thread.sleep(3000);  
  }
%>
<br/>Finished processing. Here are the results...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked . I was missing out.flush() because of which it was not showing messege.

Comment: Hi @rickz.Once my processing finishes I am displaying "finished processing" messege. But that time I want to hide "Please wait.." messege in jsp .Can you please guide me how I can go for it ?