# How can i show a loading message like "Please wait" at jsp side?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, extjs

Basically i want to show a "Please wait" loading message while some process are being execute. I tried many ext js but it doesn't work.
     Here, I am putting my jsp code as well as js code.

**This is my JS file.**

```
exportIFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
                                exportIFrame.src = "about:blank";
                                exportIFrame.width = "2px";
                                exportIFrame.height = "2px";
                                exportIFrame.style.border = 0;
                                exportIFrame.id = "loginFrame";
                                exportIFrame.name = "loginFrame";

                                document.body.appendChild(exportIFrame);

                                var idocument = exportIFrame.contentWindow.document;

                                loginForm = idocument.createElement("form");
                                loginForm.setAttribute("target", "loginFrame");
                                loginForm.setAttribute("method","Post"); 
                                loginForm.setAttribute("action","./DeliveryTech/services/GenericExportGridDataToExcel.jsp");  

                                var hiddenFieldsearchConditions = idocument.createElement("input");
                                hiddenFieldsearchConditions.setAttribute('type',"hidden");
                                hiddenFieldsearchConditions.setAttribute('name',"searchConditions");
                                hiddenFieldsearchConditions.setAttribute('value',searchConditions);
                                loginForm.appendChild(hiddenFieldsearchConditions);

                                var hiddenFieldGridName = idocument.createElement("input");
                                hiddenFieldGridName.setAttribute('type',"hidden");
                                hiddenFieldGridName.setAttribute('name',"gridName");
                                hiddenFieldGridName.setAttribute('value',gridName);
                                loginForm.appendChild(hiddenFieldGridName);

                                var hiddenFieldVisibleColumn = idocument.createElement("input");
                                hiddenFieldVisibleColumn.setAttribute('type',"hidden");
                                hiddenFieldVisibleColumn.setAttribute('name',"visibleColumn");
                                hiddenFieldVisibleColumn.setAttribute('value',Ext.util.JSON.encode(visibleColumn)); 
                                loginForm.appendChild(hiddenFieldVisibleColumn);

                                var hiddenFieldFROM = idocument.createElement("input");
                                hiddenFieldFROM.setAttribute('type',"hidden");
                                hiddenFieldFROM.setAttribute('name',"pagefrom");
                                hiddenFieldFROM.setAttribute('value',pageFrom);
                                loginForm.appendChild(hiddenFieldFROM);

                                var hiddenFieldTO = idocument.createElement("input");
                                hiddenFieldTO.setAttribute('type',"hidden");
                                hiddenFieldTO.setAttribute('name',"pageto");
                                hiddenFieldTO.setAttribute('value',pageTo);
                                loginForm.appendChild(hiddenFieldTO);

                                exportIFrame.appendChild(loginForm);
                                loginForm.submit();
```

**This is my JSP file.**

```
<%
%>
<script language="javascript">
loadMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Please wait..."});
loadMask.show();
</script>
<%
CommonLogger.getLogger().info("\n\nGenericExportGridDataToExcel.jsp: [START]"); 
String userId = "";
if(null!=bizSite && null!=bizSite.getCurrentUser()){
    userId = bizSite.getCurrentUser();
    CommonLogger.getLogger().info("\nGenericExportGridDataToExcel.jsp: userId:"+userId); 
} else {
    CommonLogger.getLogger().info("\nSession is Expired:"); 
}
//Block for User permissions on and Owning offices
JSONObject userPermissions = null;
JSONArray userPermissionsArr = null;
List<String> userAllowDashboards = new ArrayList<String>();
GlobalOrderEntryService globalOrderEntryService = new GlobalOrderEntryServiceImpl();
if(null == session.getAttribute("SDIUserDashOwningOffices")) {
    userPermissions = globalOrderEntryService.getUserPermissionAccessLevel(userId).getJSONObject("data");
    session.setAttribute("SDIUserDashOwningOffices", userPermissions);
    Iterator<?> userPermissionsKeys = userPermissions.keys();
    while( userPermissionsKeys.hasNext() ){
        String userPermKey = (String)userPermissionsKeys.next();
        userAllowDashboards.add(Constants.DASHBOARD_NAMES_MAP.get(userPermKey));
    }
    session.setAttribute("SDIUserDashboards", userAllowDashboards);
} else {
    userPermissions = JSONObject.fromObject(session.getAttribute("SDIUserDashOwningOffices"));
    userAllowDashboards = JSONArray.fromObject(session.getAttribute("SDIUserDashboards"));
}
String owningOffices="";
Object ownOffcObj = userPermissions.get(Constants.DELIVERY_TECHNICIANS_PERMISSION_STR);
if(null != ownOffcObj) {
    owningOffices = ownOffcObj.toString();
    owningOffices = owningOffices.replaceAll("\\[","").replaceAll("\\]","").replaceAll(", ", ",").replaceAll("\"","");
}   
//Block for User permissions on and Owning offices

Boolean totalRecordLimitExceed = false;
int pageFrom =0,pageTO=0,firstResult=1,maxResult=1;
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String timeStamp = format.format(new Date());
//SearchFilterParser filterParser = new SearchFilterParserImpl();
//String searchConditions = request.getParameter("searchConditions");
Properties subtitleProperties = null;
subtitleProperties = new Properties();
ClassLoader cl = Config.class.getClassLoader();
subtitleProperties.load(cl.getResourceAsStream("Subtitling.properties")); 

int perPageLimit =  Integer.parseInt(subtitleProperties.getProperty(Constants.DELIVERY_TECH_EXPORT_TO_EXCEL_PAGE_LIMIT));
int totalRecordLimit =  Integer.parseInt(subtitleProperties.getProperty(Constants.DELIVERY_TECH_EXPORT_TO_EXCEL_DATA_LIMIT));

String gridName = "";
if(null!=request.getParameter("gridName"))
    gridName = request.getParameter("gridName");
if(null!=request.getParameter("pagefrom"))
    pageFrom = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pagefrom"));
if(null!=request.getParameter("pageto"))
    pageTO = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pageto"));

LinkedHashMap<String,String> visibleColumnMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
JSONArray visibleColumns = null;
JSONObject columnObj = null;
if(null!=request.getParameter("visibleColumn")){
    visibleColumns = JSONArray.fromObject(request.getParameter("visibleColumn"));
    for(int index = 0;index < visibleColumns.size();index++){
        columnObj = visibleColumns.getJSONObject(index);
        visibleColumnMap.put(columnObj.getString("dataindex"),columnObj.getString("header"));
    }
}

String excelName = null;
Map<String,Object> map = null;
Map<String,Object> searchMap = null;
GridParams gridParams = null;
Map<String,Object> eqSearchConditions = null;
Map<String,Object> neSearchConditions = null;
String searchFor;
try {
    CommonLogger.getLogger().info("\nGenericExportGridDataToExcel.jsp: perPageLimit:"+perPageLimit +"\t totalRecordLimit:"+totalRecordLimit);
    CommonLogger.getLogger().info("\nGenericExportGridDataToExcel.jsp: pageFrom:"+pageFrom +"\t pageTO:"+pageTO); 
    if(pageFrom !=0 && pageTO != 0){
        firstResult=pageFrom;
        if(pageFrom == pageTO){
            maxResult = perPageLimit;
        }else if(pageTO > pageFrom){
            maxResult = (((pageTO - pageFrom) +1 )* perPageLimit);
        }
        if(maxResult>totalRecordLimit){
            totalRecordLimitExceed =true;
        }
    }else if(pageTO != 0){ 
        firstResult=pageFrom;
        maxResult = pageTO;
    }
    CommonLogger.getLogger().info("\nGenericExportGridDataToExcel.jsp: firstResult:"+firstResult +"\t maxResult:"+maxResult);
    if(!totalRecordLimitExceed){
        Map<String,Object> map1 = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        map1.put(Constants.GRID_PARAMS_OBJECT_KEY,gridParams);
        HashMap<String,Object> searchConditions = new HashMap<String,Object>();

        final String searchCondition;

        searchCondition=request.getParameter("searchConditions");
        JSONArray searchConditionJSONArray = JSONArray.fromObject(request.getParameter("searchConditions"));
        JSONObject searchConditionJSONObject = null;

        map1.put(Constants.EQ_SEARCH_PARAMS_MAP_KEY,new HashMap<String,Object>(){{put("searchConditions",searchCondition);}});
        if(map!=null){
            gridParams = (map.get(Constants.GRID_PARAMS_OBJECT_KEY)!=null?((GridParams)map.get(Constants.GRID_PARAMS_OBJECT_KEY)):null);
            eqSearchConditions = (map.get(Constants.EQ_SEARCH_PARAMS_MAP_KEY)!=null?(Map<String, Object>)map.get(Constants.EQ_SEARCH_PARAMS_MAP_KEY):null);
            neSearchConditions = (map.get(Constants.NE_SEARCH_PARAMS_MAP_KEY)!=null?(Map<String, Object>)map.get(Constants.NE_SEARCH_PARAMS_MAP_KEY):null);
        }
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        if(gridName!=null) {
            DeliveryTechServiceImpl deliveryTechDefaultService = new DeliveryTechServiceImpl();
            if(Constants.DELIVERY_TECH_DEFAULTVIEW_GRIDNAME.equals(gridName)) {
                wb = deliveryTechDefaultService.exportToExcelDefaultView(map1,visibleColumnMap,"Default",owningOffices,firstResult,maxResult);
                excelName = Constants.DELIVERY_TECH_DEFAULTVIEW_EXCELNAME;
            }else if(Constants.DELIVERY_TECH_PLANINGVIEW_GRIDNAME.equals(gridName)) {
                wb = deliveryTechDefaultService.exportToExcelDefaultView(map1,visibleColumnMap,"Planing",owningOffices,firstResult,maxResult);
                excelName = Constants.DELIVERY_TECH_PLANINGVIEW_EXCELNAME;
            }
        } 
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Expires:", "0"); // eliminates browser caching
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+excelName+"_"+timeStamp+".xls");

        wb.write(response.getOutputStream());
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        response.getOutputStream().close();
    }else{
        %>
            <script language="javascript">
                loadMask.hide();
                alert("Total record limit exceeded. Please enter valid page length.");
            </script>
        <%
    }
    %>
    <script language="javascript">
        loadMask.hide();
    </script>
    <%
    CommonLogger.getLogger().info("\n\nGenericExportGridDataToExcel.jsp: [END]"); 
} catch (Exception ex) {
    %>
    <script language="javascript">
        loadMask.hide();
    </script>
    <%
    CommonLogger.getLogger().info("\n\n Error in GenericExportGridDataToExcel.jsp"+ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(ex)); 
    //e.printStackTrace();
}
  %>
```

Please focus on `<script>` tag not entire jsp code.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044079/display-messesge-wait-as-background-processing-happening/10059079#10059079

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, I did something similar before using jQuery/Ajax.

I implementated this way:

JSP:

```
<div id="loading" style="background:url('<c:url value="path to your gif img"/>')50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249)">
    <label class="loading-msg">Please wait....</label>
</div>
```

In JS:

```
function beforeProcess() {
    $('#loading').show();
});

function afterProcess() {
    $('#loading').fadeOut(3000);
});
```

Your CSS:

```
#loading {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

I am not sure but you can call these functions before the process and when the process is complete(successful or failure) you can hide/fadeout the element.

Answer (score 0):

Do some reading up on AJAX. I can't think of any other way really to do this using a native JSP based way.

The general idea would be that you would use AJAX to make a call to the process that takes a while, rendering a 'Please Wait' message whilst the call is executing. Once the call has finished executing, you can then render the output.

Edit - the focus on `<script>` tag makes me think (if this is an assignment) that you're supposed to do this using an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you use extjs. If so, you can always use the

`Ext.getCmp('yourelementid').setLoading(true);` to start

and

`Ext.getCmp('yourelementid').setLoading(false);` to stop

The above will be handy if your extjs layout is up and running. But if you want to display a loading mask when your jsp page loads, that is another story. If this is your case do as follows:

this is your html within the jsp file:

`<body>
    <div id="loading-mask"></div>
        <div id="loading">
          <div class="loading-indicator">
             Loading ....
          </div>

        </div>
  </body>`

this is your css:

```
#loading-mask {
  position: absolute;
  left:     0;
  top:      0;
  width:    100%;
  height:   100%;
  z-index:  20000;
  background-color: white;
}

#loading {
  position: absolute;
  left:     50%;
  top:      50%;
  padding:  2px;
  z-index:  20001;
  height:   auto;
  margin:   -35px 0 0 -30px;
}

#loading .loading-indicator {
  background: url(images/extanim32.gif) no-repeat; //just replace with an animated gif
  color:      #555;
  font:       bold 13px tahoma,arial,helvetica;
  padding:    8px 42px;
  margin:     0;
  text-align: center;
  height:     auto;
}
```

and finally your js:

```
 Ext.onReady(function() { 
          setTimeout(function(){
              Ext.get('loading').fadeOut({
              remove:true,
              easing: 'easeOut',
              duration: 2000
              });
              Ext.get('loading-mask').fadeOut({
              remove:true,
              easing: 'easeOut',
              duration: 2000
              });
            }, 250);
});
```