# Display wait message during processing of submit button click

Tags: jsp, servlets, servlet-3.0

I am working on application using Jsp and Servlet as a controller.

Here's the scenario : 
Page1 contains a form which when the user submit it is passed to controller, from controller calls DAO to fetch data from DB and then forwards to Page2. Page2 takes considerable time to load since it retrieves lot of its content from the DB.

How can I implement something where once the user submits form on Page1, a "Please wait..." message or a screen loads up and then as soon as Page2 is ready it forwards to Page2?

I tried the below work around but it is showing Processing message as soon as when I click the Page 1 from Left Menu Page link.

[Display messesge wait....as background processing happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044079/display-messesge-wait-as-background-processing-happening)

I need to display message when the user clicks submit button.

Any body help an easy method if possible step by step.

My code is like below:
Page 1 contains:

```
<form name="siteSearchForm" method=post action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/servlet/visibilityController" onsubmit="javascript:return validate()">


  <td align="center" width="10%"><input type=submit name="siteSearchSubmit" value="SUBMIT" >&nbsp;<input type="RESET" name="clearTN" value="RESET"></td>
```

Once click the Submit button to goes to controller in the below logic:
Added only logic here.

```
 woNumber = request.getParameter("orderNum");

                    session.setAttribute("orderNum",woNumber);


                    flow = "OrderDetailsSearchFlow";
                    rd = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/SearchDetails.jsp");
                    OrderDAOBean woDaoBean = new OrderDAOBean();

                List workOrderBean = woDaoBean.getOrderDetails(woNumber);           



                    if(workOrderBean.size() == 0){
                        rd = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/ExceptionPage.jsp");
                        request.setAttribute("errorMessage","No Records Returned for Work Order Search Results, Order Number = "+woNumber);
                        rd.forward(request, response);
                    }
                    else{
                        request.setAttribute("pagePosition","0");
                        HttpSession serialSession = request.getSession(true);
                        serialSession.setAttribute("OrderSearchDetails", workOrderBean);
                        serialSession.setAttribute("OrderNum",woNumber);
                        request.setAttribute("OrderSearchDetails",workOrderBean);

                        session.setAttribute("flow",flow);

                        rd.forward(request, response);
                    }
                }
```

Thanks advance

Comment: In addition to validating the form using JavaScript, display a loading message.

Comment: Hi But I need  validation also please suggest if you want will post the javascript

Comment: That's why I said "in addition to validating", and not "instead of validating".

Comment: Thanks sorry its misunderstood. Can you help me with example to display a loading message in addition to validation any samples please

Comment: Use Google. You just need to get some hidden DOM element containing the message and to make it visible.